# Data Validation Source - Offset From More Than One Source - Sheet

Tags: excel

I have the following OFFSET equation that works like a charm:

`=OFFSET('Sheet 1'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet 1'!$A:$A)-1)`

The issue is I need to choose values from more than just sheet 1, 6 other sheets to be exact.

The following equation does not work:

`=OFFSET('Sheet 1'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet 1'!$A:$A)-1), OFFSET('Sheet 2'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet 2'!$A:$A)-1)`

Comment: You are not going be able to do this directly in Data validation.  You will need to create a dynamic list somewhere to which you refer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What about in Name Manager?

Comment: You will need to have a helper column of cells that dynamically include all the values you want.  Then you would refer to that column.  You cannot use array type formula in Data Validation and trying to load 6 sheets will require that.  And no a formula in name manager will not do it either for the same reason.

Comment: Everything that I can find for a helper column refers to searching a column in the same sheet. For each sheet I am trying to get all values from A4:A(dynamic value).

Comment: That is because it is very difficult to do without the new dynamic array formula HSTACK.  If you do not have it then writing vba in worksheet change events will be the best route.

Comment: Would it require VSTACK instead? Just now reading up on it, pretty neat stuff

Comment: Yes, sorry VSTACK.  `=VSTACK(FILTER('Sheet1'!A4:A1040000,'Sheet1'!A4:A1040000<>"",""),FILTER('Sheet2'!A4:A1040000,'Sheet2'!A4:A1040000<>"",""),...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247927/discussion-between-beerusdev-and-scott-craner).